# Magento event for leaving a page

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to do some data cleanup when a user leaves the page that my module affects, I can put all of the cleanup logic wherever I need to but my question is:
**Is there any event or method that is called when a user leaves a given page and if so what is it and how do I call it/config it**

Comment: What do you mean, "leaves a page"? Goes from one page in your app to the next? Leaves the site entirely? Closes the browser without navigating elsewhere?

Comment: is this a joke? :) you should leave magento alone if you are asking this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only fire an ajax request:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  //alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
  YOUR_AJAX_CALL();
});
```

As PHP is stateless and only acting on requests, there is no PHP way to detect if a window closes, this is happening on client side!

If you just mean "when a customer logout happens", you could use:

`controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account`